# Connect\join multiple vertices to one

Tags: add-on, vertices, topology

[image: What i have]

I need to make topology tris\quad. So usualy i join verteces one by one to opposite vertex. But in most cases i need to join many verteces to only one or two. Its not hard but it is time consuming.
So the question is there an easier way to join them? For example join all selected to last selected or something like this? Some add-on?
[image: What i need]

Comment: Merge Vertices -> At last is a real tool… what do you mean?

Comment: I think he means 'join with edges' rather than merging verts, presumably to try to avoid shading problems.

Comment: If this is to avoid shading problems, see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T3QdLJOBF8&list=PLI7lUjDimZF08eAN--H0GxsaucE522cIB&index=7) YT video from Josh Gambrell which might help.

Comment: I mean join vertices, not merge them. Join 2 vertices, one from circle and an other from main part of the object.
Also not a shading issue. Topology issue. How to make topology with less effort.

Comment: I don't think that sort of join will improve your topology, so that means I don't understand what you're trying.  What do what to accomplish by just a join?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of a native way, maybe there's some addon..?
here's a little script that should work on a topolgy like that

```
# connect selected vertices to active one in edit mode

import bpy, bmesh
ob = bpy.context.object

bm = bmesh.new()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)
bm.verts.index_update()
active = bm.select_history[-1]
select = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
select.remove(active)

for v in select:
    verts = [active, v]
    bmesh.ops.connect_vert_pair(bm, verts=verts)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(ob.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use addon interactive tools, the function is called super smart create, it does exactly what you need on verts, it can[image] also fills selected edges with faces.